# jQuery does not work for me on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, yaml

I´m having a headache last two days with Google App Engine and JQuery.

I try to implement the jQuery in the html file and I created de handler in app.yaml, but still does not work. This worked with my css and images, but I´m stuck with the JavaScript.

I also tried to do the same page without Google App Engine AND WORKED!! Why the same code does not work when I display it in my localserver ????

Here goes my app.yaml handler:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: static_files/js
```

My call in the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static_files/js/jquery.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static_files/js/script.js"></script>
```

and the jquery itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ingles").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

I know that the javascript code works fine, and I suppose the html call is correct. Maybe the mistake is in the app.yaml? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your static URL to be `/js` but in your HTML you are requesting `/static_files/js`. You should use just `/js` there too.

The way to start debugging issues like this is by trying to go to the location mentioned in the link, and seeing if that works.

Comment: Thanks! I tried: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"</script> and <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script> , but still don´t work..

Comment: And what does happen if you go to that url directly in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/js/script.js show me the javascript code as expected: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ingles").fadeOut(1000);
});

Comment: If localhost:8080/js/script.js shows me my javascript code, I should supose that the .yaml file is ok and also the html. I know that the javascript code itself works. So where is the mistake? Maybe GoogleW App Engine does not display jquery efects in the browser for any reason? should I change my main.py file? Looks like the only option.. Thanks

Comment: If the code is loading properly, that's all App Engine can do. It doesn't have anything to do with allowing it to display: you just need HTML and JS for that.

Comment: The thing is that the .js files and also the link src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" works when i copy all the code and I launch it in the browser from the hard drive, BUT boths ways does not work when I launch it in localserver from App Engine